# ReactRouter doesn't redirect correctly after flux notification

Tags: redirect, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, flux

I'm a newbie in react and flux. As a matter of facts I stumbled into the following problem when using ReactRouter (2.4)

I'm using hashHistory and I need to redirect to the "/" page when I'm in "/login" page after a successful login attempt.

**Router**

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={ErasmusPage} onEnter={authCheck}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="login"component={withRouter(LoginPage)}></Route>
    </Route>
</Router>, app);
```

**Login Page**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.notifyLogin = this.notifyLogin.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    authStore.on("login", this.notifyLogin);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    authStore.removeListener("login", this.notifyLogin);
}

notifyLogin() {
    this.props.router.push('/');
}

...

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    };
    AuthActions.authenticate(data);
}
...
```

The flow is:

1. after one submits, authActions and Store elaborate the datas (ajax call involved).
2. If the login attempt is all right, AuthStore emits a "login" signal...
3. ... so i can execute notifyLogin().

The problem is: this.props.router.push('/') doesn't redirect properly, it changes the URL but not the page (it looks like the state refresh doesn't get triggered).

Weird thing is, if I put this.props.router.push('/') in the handleSubmit function the redirect works perfectly.

Any idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked well for me so far:

- Wrap your app in an  component that contains login/auth state.
- on render, if not logged in, render the login page component, otherwise, render the app component

```js
render() {
  const { isAuthorized, authError} = this.props;
  
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return (<Layout />);
  }
  
  return (<Login authError={authError}/>);
}
```

Comment: Uhm, yes. I know I can do that. The point, although, was doing it using the notification from the store to trigger the switch inside on the calling component. I dug more deeply and I beleive it's something related to the stack of calls.
The emission in the store calls the "notify" in the component, than in the same call I try to swap component but the stack call tries to go backward in the wrong context... it must be something like that...

Comment: Uhmm, more and more convinced that if I did an async callback it could have worked I tryed with an:

    setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.router.push('/');
    }, 1000);

It works, but it's an hack... anyone's got a better idea?
Is it THAT wrong passing the promise of axios to the store instead of dispatching in the callbacks?

Comment: Ah, ok @user3549754 then still, your component just triggers a login action.  if login succeeds, that action dispatches a user_authenticated action, which sets that on the login store.  Now your login store will receive new props.  Add a componentWillUpdate that redirects if userAuthenticated prop is true.

Comment: Uhmm, so, even if I wanted to keep the things isolated in the lower component I guess the best way is to put a "userAuthenticated" state in the father node. It would have spared me a lot of sweat and, after all, the solution is clean anyway. Thank you for the help. Really!

Comment: Sure, glad to help.